# Open TexMaker using terminal

Tags: texmaker

How can I setup a TexMaker to open from terminal. I install using `brew` but trying to figure out how I can set it up to open a directory or a file using terminal.

Comment: I don't think one can install Texmaker via `brew`.

Answer (score 3):

TexMaker is a normal command

```
$ which texmaker
/usr/bin/texmaker
$ texmaker foo.tex
```